# OpenGL ES attribute transfer default behaviour when dimensions don't match

Tags: opengl-es

Running a very simple OpenGL ES example I've seen that the dimensions of the position attribute in the vertex shader and the ones used to transfer the attribute data to the GPU are different, but the example runs correctly.

This is the attribute declaration in the vertex shader:

```
attribute vec4 a_v4Position;
```

And this is how the attribute value is transferred:

```
const float triangleVertices[] =
{
     0.0f,  0.5f, 0.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
     0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
};

positionAttribLocation = glGetAttribLocation(GLProgram, "a_v4Position"); //GLProgram is the linked program
glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionAttribLocation);
glVertexAttribPointer(positionAttribLocation, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, TriangleVertices);
```

So, why this works fine and which is the "w" default value that results from this process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `w` will be 1.0 in this case. This is perfectly legal and well defined. Whenever the specified attribute has fewer values than 4, the missing values are padded with values from (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0). Of course, if the attribute vector in the vertex shader is shorter, not all those values are used.

The relevant spec language is on page 21 of the ES 2.0 spec, under "Transferring Array Elements":

> When an array element i is transferred to the GL by the DrawArrays or DrawElements commands, each generic attribute is expanded to four components. If size is one then the x component of the attribute is speciﬁed by the array; the y, z, and w components are implicitly set to zero, zero, and one, respectively. If size is two then the x and y components of the attribute are speciﬁed by the array; the z, and w components are implicitly set to zero, and one, respectively. If size is three then x, y, and z are speciﬁed, and w is implicitly set to one. If size is four then all components are speciﬁed.