# Trouble with Simple Triangle in OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk, opengl-es-2.0

I'm having an issue drawing a simple triangle.  I have OpenGL ES 2.0 in Android Native Activity setup correctly because I can do glClear() and it works.

When I try to draw a triangle with 3 vertices, it either crashes on a glDrawArrays call or if I try to do glDrawElements, nothing happens, but I get the following message: GLES_V2//GLESv2Imp.cpp:glDrawElements:669 error 0x500

I looked it up, but I don't think I have any invalid Enums, I've been going through my code and experimenting for a couple days but the draw calls just don't work.  I also read that glDrawArrays will crash if it tries to access wrong a wrong memory block, but as far as I can tell, my setup is correct.  Can anyone help me understand why it could possibly be crashing?

**This is how my triangle functions are called.  This part is just a mock up**

```
start()
{
  setTriangle();
}

renderLoop()
{
  drawTriangle();
}
```

**Here are my shaders:**

```
static const std::string triVertShader = "\
attribute vec4 vPosition;\
void main()\
{\
    gl_Position = vPosition;\
}\
";

static const std::string triFragShader = "\
    precision mediump float;\
    uniform vec4 vColor;\
    void main()\
    {\
        gl_FragColor = vColor;\
    }\
";
```

**This is where I compile them and Link program.  I haven't included my checks but the shaders compiled successfully, and program linked successfully:**

```
GLuint LoadShaders(const std::string &vertexShader, const std::string &fragmentShader)
{
    GLint result = GL_TRUE;
    int infoLogLength;

    //Create the shaders
    GLuint vertShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    GLuint fragShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    const char * vertShaderSource = vertexShader.data();
    const char * fragShaderSource = fragmentShader.data();

    //Compile Vertex Shader
    glShaderSource(vertShaderID, 1, &vertShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertShaderID);

    //Compile Fragment Shader
    glShaderSource(fragShaderID, 1, &fragShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragShaderID);

    //Link the program
    GLuint programID = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(programID, vertShaderID);
    glAttachShader(programID, fragShaderID);

    glBindAttribLocation(programID, 0, "vPosition");

    glLinkProgram(programID);

   // glDeleteShader(vertShaderID);
   // glDeleteShader(fragShaderID);

    return programID;
}
```

**This is where I set up the buffer object:**

```
void setTriangle()
{
  glClearColor(0, 1, 0, 1);

  GLfloat triVerts[] = {  0.0f,  0.5f, 0.0f,
                         -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
                          0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f };

  GLuint triVertBufferID;  
  glGenBuffers(1, &triVertBufferID); 

  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, triVertBufferID); 

  glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,   
               sizeof(triVerts),  
               triVerts,          
               GL_STATIC_DRAW);   

  program = LoadShaders(triVertShader, triFragShader); //note: "program" is a global variable of type GLuint

}
```

**Here is the draw call:**

```
void drawTriangle()
{

  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

  glUseProgram(program);

  glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

  glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);   

  //glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 3, GL_FLOAT, (void*)0 );

  //glDrawArrays always crashes immediately
  glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);          

}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are some minor issues that I can see which are causing your app to not render:

You've declared your vPosition attribute as a vec4, but you are initializing it with not enough data. OpenGL will fill in the missing data with default values, but this could still lead to unexpected behavior.

```
//call me after programID = loadShaders(...)
int vPosLoc = GLES20.getAttributeLocation(programID,"vPosition"); //pass me to EnableVertexAttribArray()!
```

Just as you did when initializing the data, when rendering you need to bind a buffer to connect it to the shader input - so:

```
glUseProgram(program);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(vPosLoc); //you use 0 for vPosLoc, which only works because you called glBindAttributeLocation()
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, triVertBufferID); //triVertBufferID - make it a class member?
glVertexAttribPointer(vPosLoc, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0); //you might need to change the second argument from 3 to 4, if you're gonna stick with vec4 for vPosition in the shader.
```

Note that I changed your 0's to vPosLoc  in vertexAttribPointer and enableVertexAttribArray(), simply for the sake of using variables not constants.

You (in the code you've shown) never set the vColor uniform variable - you'll need to do that, and you'll need to look up its shader location:

```
//set me up right after loadShaders()
int vColorLoc = glGetUniformLocation(programID,"vColor");


//and later, in draw
glUniform4f(vColorLoc,1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0); //red!
```

Now, you should be able to call glDrawArrays()!

Comment: The first two items listed here are not issues. It's perfectly valid to declare the attribute variable in the shader with more components than the specified attributes (see for example this recent question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31319081/3530129). On the attribute location, the OP calls `glBindAttribLocation()` to set it to 0, so there's no problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I actually arrived at basically what you said and then saw your reply - I was able to see a green screen without any crashes.  Anyways, I just had the red color hard coded in the fragment shader but I changed it to what you said.  I changed everything else to exactly as you said and I still get the same result: green screen.  This is clearly better than a crash but still not the desired effect.  Still not rendering a triangle.  I've littered the entire file with glGetError statements, and everything is returning a 0 (no error).  Anyways, then I found my stupid error

Comment: I was doing glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, **1**); just to see if I was going over the buffer during the crash.  I forgot to switch it back.  Now I'm getting a triangle!!  Thank you very much, I'm going to credit you with the solution.  There was another issue too..  the Native Activity Code from google was doing `glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_FASTEST);` but GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION is deprecated!  It kept giving me false 0x500 errors (for every gl call) when trying to debug and led me on a wild goose chase.  I will update the main post with my findings later when I get a chance.

Comment: @RetoKoradi - thanks for the good info - I missed the call to bindAttribLocation, and I was unaware that GL would fill in missing data for the vec4 attribute. I'll update the answer to remove the incorrect information. Smokenstein - glad you figured out the issue!

Answer (score 0):

This call is invalid:

```
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 3, GL_FLOAT, (void*)0 );
```

The parameter `GL_FLOAT` is not a valid data type for index data, GLES 2.x only supports `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` and `GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT`.

However, I think you do not intend to use `glDrawElements()` at all. That is for [indexed rendering](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Index_buffers). In your code, you don't prepare any `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`, and you don't need one.

You probably want to use

```
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
```

Als make sure that `triVertBufferID` is still the currently bound `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` at the time of the `glVertexAttribPointer()` call in `drawTriangle()`. Currently, you only bind it `setTriangle()` at the program initialization. This will work as long as you never bind anything else to that buffer target (or explicitely unbind it). If you want to add different objects later, this will cause an issue.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, and you're right, I do want to use glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);  But that crashes, right away, without any explanation.  I'm running it on an emulator and normally when there's a crash, it says "the app has stopped working" but this glDrawArrays() crash completely crashes the emulator.  So my question is Why does glDrawArrays() crash so "violently"

Answer (score 0):

In short, you don't have indices and color datas, and also you don't bind VBO that you made as a vertices buffer. Color is not necessary if you take color off in Frag Shader code. Put gl_FragColor = vec(1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0); instead for testing if it works well.

Updated)

1. make the local vertices array a global array.

   GLfloat triVerts[] = {  0.0f,  0.5f, 0.0f,
                            -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
                             0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f };
2. bind vbo using the variable, **triVertBufferID** in the func in a render loop
3. When you use VBO and it is static(never change), don't call glVertexAttribPointer(), glEnableVertexAttribArray() every time. You can set it once in setTriangle(), and you are not sure if its handle id is '0'. you should call glGetAttribLocation() to know it.

   When you don't use VBO, call those funcs every time with the pointer of vertices array.

Comment: VAOs are not part of the ES 2 spec. They might be available as extension, but their use is not mandatory.

Comment: I was trying to say VBO.

Comment: I am binding it. Can you clarify what you mean?                              `GLuint triVertBufferID;  
  glGenBuffers(1, &triVertBufferID); 

  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, triVertBufferID); 

  glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,   
               sizeof(triVerts),  
               triVerts,          
               GL_STATIC_DRAW); `

Comment: Normally, each frame, you should bind it again. Each VBO like color, vertice and indice must be bind in render() func so VAO pops up to help it to be simple (Android doesn't officially support it though)

Comment: gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0); didn't do anything

Comment: Not bad, that means your vertices are not passed. It should be a red triangle. Let's find why.

Comment: That may not know what the vertices array is because it is a local array I think. Updated my answer. For a practice, I would recommend to use multi FBOs RBOs VBOs it will help you to understand more about it.

Comment: Still nothing.  All of the examples I've looked at did it how I have it in my original post.  See this example: [https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/hello-gl2-Android-3b61896c/sourcecode?fileId=135959&pathId=913373117]

Comment: Did you do all I updated ? if so, don't use VBO first. Skip those glgenbuffer, glbindbuffer, glbufferdata and put glVertexAttribPointer(id, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0,triVerts ); glEnableVertexAttribArray(id); in drawTriangle()

Comment: Do you now see the green screen by the way?

Comment: Wait let me understand this properly:  Put glGenBuffer, glBindBuffer, glBufferData into setTriangle().  Put glVertexAttribPointer, glEnableVertexAttribArray into drawTriangle()?  If so, that's how I already have in my original post.  Is that what you meant?

Comment: I mean, take out  glGenBuffer, glBindBuffer, glBufferData from setTriangle() and put glVertexAttribPointer, glEnableVertexAttribArray  in drawTriangle. Then change this glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0,0) to glVertexAttribPointer(id returned from glGetAttribLocation(), 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0,triVerts) Is that clear?

Comment: If i take out glGenBuffer, glBindBuffer, glBufferData from setTriangle() then where is it supposed to happen?

Comment: Those functions are for VBOs which are not required so for testing, just pass the vertices to  glVertexAttribPointer(,,,,here). Anyway, if you don't see the green screen now, the real problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: Hey @SungWoo that was a good thought.  I did what you suggested and also put `program = LoadShaders(triVertShader, triFragShader);` inside drawTriangle() before glUseProgram() but I still get a crash when glDrawArrays() happens.  So I commented out the glDrawArrays line so I could see the debug log statements.  I put a check on the glAttachShader() statement for if the shaders were getting attached succesfully.  It looks like the vertex shader isn't getting attached.  I get the following output for the Vertex Shader: **glAttachShader() glError (0x500)** which I think means invalid enum.

Comment: I should add that compiling the shaders didn't cause any errors.  I don't get how it could compile successfully but have an invalid enum for attaching when glAttachShader() doesn't take any enums.  ThoughtS?

Comment: Why don't you try to build a NDK example? If you are a OpenGL beginner Don't make all yourself. Already, there are too many things to do.